# Custom marker in google map not match to coordinate

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using a custom marker (Because that i'm a new user can't upload image) that its marker is in the left side of image.

the problem is that the image not match to the coordinate that i want to show it. it goes to the left side of coordinate and it is because that the arrow is in the left side of image.
I have some search about this and in [android custom map marker bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975553/android-custom-map-marker-bounds) that i should to use `SetBounds` to resolve it.
But the second problem is that by using `Setbounds` it change the size of images and it looks by bad quality in screen.there is not any other ways to match the custom marker in to coordinates?
This is the code that i use in my overlay constructor:

```
    marker .SetBounds (0, -(int) Common.convertPixelsToDp (marker .IntrinsicHeight  ,act.ApplicationContext ) ,
                          (int) Common.convertPixelsToDp (marker .IntrinsicWidth ,act.ApplicationContext )/2,0);
```

Comment: Does your marker have shadow (to the right)? This could be the issue with showing marker on the left.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yes my marker have this.How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Edit marker image with any Image Editing tool (eg. GIMP or Photoshop)and remove shadow and make your marker at center of the image. that will solve issue you are facing

Comment: OK.There is not any other way that i keep the shadow?I saw that marker have shadow with itself in google maps.

Comment: yes there is way .. keep shadow but increase width of marker to the left side of marker so that marker will be at the center of the image. Making marker center of the image you are using will do the trick for you

Comment: The problem was because of that my marker have shadow.The monodroid itself add shadow automatically for markers. Therefore i removed the shadow and changed the marker image how to be in center of image and then the problem fixed. Thanks to all.Was good point.